# ASP.NET / Android / iOS - Cross-platform data-exchange - JSON or what else?

Tags: asp.net, ios, json, web-services, cross-platform

actually I'm planning on doing a little bigger project. I want to make an Android-App, iOS-App and a ASP.NET web-page, and all three should use the same DataBase (preferable MS SQL Server).

Is JSON the best choice? When yes, how do I have to build up the whole thing? 
Can I write only one service and every plattform then can read and send to this service?
What kind of service should that be, so I can look further what I have to learn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server, I assume you are using C# or VB.NET.

You can write a single service with Web API and it can output both XML and JSON. You can configure the default output format to be one or the other - for example, you can configure the API to by default emit JSON objects, but if the person requesting data specifies an HTTP header, you can emit XML instead.

But currently JSON is the standard for web services, so I would go with JSON and build around that.

Comment: that's pretty much what I wanted to know. But I guess for hosting the Web API I need a special hoster, right? Or does it work on nearly every Microsoft-hoster?

Comment: I'm not aware of needing a special hoster. You mean a special environment? As long as you have a Windows machine with IIS and .NET 4.0 (I don't think it needs 4.5, but I could be wrong), you should be fine.

Comment: ok, just never saw something related to a service on the ftp-server for the aspx-files. But Windows-Azure can do it 100%, and i guess i will join this. Thx for the answer, question's solved

Answer (score 1):

You can make a ASMX service or WCF service and you can use these service in web using javascript or by codebehind For Android and ios you can call webservice by requesting in json format actually one asmx service can response XML as well as JSON format